# Why am I missing the outer div of my HTML block when I use JQuery's $.parseHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When I parse an html string with `$.parseHTML()`, the outer most div disappears.

Given the html string:

```
var myCode = '<div class="outer">' +
    '    <div class="inner">' +
    '        <div>' +
    '            <p>Hello!</p>' +
    '        </div>' +
    '        <div>' +
    '            <p>Hello!!' +
    '            </p>' +
    '        </div>' +
    '    </div>' +
    '</div>';
```

When I call parse this html, the outer most div (`class="outer"`) isn't present.

```
var $myHtmlObject = $($.parseHTML(myCode)) 
console.log($myHtmlObject.html()) // no "outer" div present.
```

[I made a jsfiddle to show the behavior](http://jsfiddle.net/3gxEM/10/)

I can easily get around this by wrapping everything in *another* `div` before I parse it, but that seems like a hack for something that should otherwise work.

Comment: "Get the HTML contents of the first element in the set of matched elements or set the HTML contents of every matched element." http://api.jquery.com/html/

Answer (score 4):

Because .html() gives the inner html of the first element of the set of element on which it was called. What you are looking for here is the `outerHTML`

```
console.log($myHtmlObject[0].outerHTML)
console.log($myHtmlObject.prop('outerHTML'))
```

Also there is no need to use parseHTML() in this case

```js
var log = (function() {
  var $log = $('#log');
  return function(msg) {
    $('<p/>', {
      text: msg
    }).appendTo($log)
  }
})();


var myCode = '<div class="outer">' +
  '    <div class="inner">' +
  '        <div>' +
  '            <p>Hello!</p>' +
  '        </div>' +
  '        <div>' +
  '            <p>Hello!!' +
  '            </p>' +
  '        </div>' +
  '    </div>' +
  '</div>';

var $html = $(myCode);
log('html: ' + $html.html())
log('outer-html: ' + $html.prop('outerHTML'))
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="log"></div>
```